# Setting properties to only input boxes and not buttons

Tags: javascript, dom

I need your help,

The following javascript code apparently, attaches itself to my input boxes and buttons. Why would it attach it self to my buttons? When the only thing that I want it to attach to is my input type="text" only.

```
    // HANDLE ALL INPUT/TEXT BOXES
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        alert(x[i].id)         
            if (!x[i].readOnly) {
                if (x[i].id == "refdocs_input") {
                    x[i].onfocus = document.getElementById('refdocs_select').onfocus = function() {
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = shade;
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_select').style.backgroundColor = shade;
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_input').style.backgroundColor = shade;
                    }//end function
                    x[i].onblur = document.getElementById('refdocs_select').onblur = function() {
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = unshade;
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_select').style.backgroundColor = unshade;
                            document.getElementById('refdocs_input').style.backgroundColor = unshade;
                    }//end function
                }//end if
                else {
                    x[i].onfocus = function() { this.style.backgroundColor = shade }
                    x[i].onblur = function() {  this.style.backgroundColor = unshade }     
                }//end else
            }//end if
        }//end for
```

HTML coding for buttons:

```
    <div style="float: left; padding-left:  20px; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="search" value="Search" onclick="imts_eval_search()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="save" value="Save" onclick="imts_save_changes()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="imts_add_new()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="clearall" value="Clear all" onclick="reset_fields()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="test101()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="recall" value="Recall" onclick="imts_eval_search('recall')"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" class="button" id="debug" value="Debug" onclick="test()"></div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;"><input type="button" id="test_save" value="Save Changes" disabled/></div>
```

Comment: At a quick glance i would say because you are looping over all `input` elements and not checking for what `type` they are. `<input type="button" />` is also an input therefore your code is including them. Add a conditional testing for `if(x[i].type != "text") return false` or something along those lines

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');` then it will take all inputs since your buttons are also input. Change to `input[type="text"]`

Comment: @ShijuKBabu `input[type="text"]` is a CSS selector, how will that affect his JavaScript?

Comment: @MarkWalters I guess thats wrong. I think it must be `input:text`. But not sure. I am not good in javascript. I was just pointing the OP is selecting all inputs instead of text alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using an input. just use a `<button>`

A button on it's own should submit the form, if not use `<button type="submit">`

or you could check the type

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].type === 'text') {
       // stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple check

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT').].getAttribute("type") == "text")  {
    // do stuff here
}
```

This should take care of two cases

```
<input type="button">
  and 
<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the querySelectorAll method. It takes one or more CSS selectors and returns an array of DOM nodes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
```

for text-type input tags.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"], button');
```

for buttons and button-type inputs.